# How can I retrieve the data in field <event><payload><company><name> in ruby on rails

Tags: xml, ruby-on-rails-3, nokogiri

How can I retrieve the data in field `<event><payload><company><name>` in ruby on rails?

```
tempvariable contains the below xml data:

<event xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
<type>SUBSCRIPTION_ORDER</type>
<marketplace>
<baseUrl>https://acme.appdirect.com</baseUrl>
<partner>ACME</partner>
</marketplace>
<flag>STATELESS</flag>
<creator>
<email>test-email+creator@appdirect.com</email>
<firstName>DummyCreatorFirst</firstName>
<language>fr</language>
<lastName>DummyCreatorLast</lastName>
<openId>https://www.appdirect.com/openid/id/ec5d8eda-5cec-444d-9e30-125b6e4b67e2</openId>
<uuid>ec5d8eda-5cec-444d-9e30-125b6e4b67e2</uuid>
</creator>
<payload>
<company>
<country>CA</country>
<email>company-email@example.com</email>
<name>Example Company Name</name>
<phoneNumber>415-555-1212</phoneNumber> 
<uuid>d15bb36e-5fb5-11e0-8c3c-00262d2cda03</uuid>
</company>
</payload>
<returnUrl>https://www.appdirect.com/finishprocure?token=dummyOrder</returnUrl>
</event>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
tempvariable = request_from_marketplace(params["eventUrl"])
doc = Nokogiri::XML(tempvariable)
doc.xpath('//company').each do |char_element|
  puts char_element.xpath('name').try(:text)
end
```

Comment: I don't have any xml file.. that xml data is stored in variable called user_details.

Comment: I am trying something like the below :

doc = Nokogiri::XML(tempvariable)
    doc.search('//company').each do |company|
      typevar   = company.at('name').text
      puts typevar
end

Comment: @AsitGhosh: Please edit your question with details. and yes above comment will work. Let me you if this not worked.

Comment: I have added anathor image of my code.. kindly have a look into it. thanks!

Comment: I have made the changes as you asked.. kindly have a look into it. Thanks!

Comment: @AsitGhosh: You need to fetch company name right? So what is the output of this in your code `puts char_element.xpath('name').text`. This will probably give you the company name. what else you want?

Comment: @AsitGhosh: please check `tempvariable` variable and paste in question if possible.